# Top 3 rows based on score, but to handle ties

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've an SQL table with this structure

```
Stud Name     Score
---------------------
 Alex          7
 John         5.6
 Tom          8.2
 Antony        6
 George        9
 Mathew        7
 Jim          5.5
```

I need to find top three students based on score.

So my query is

```
select top 3 * from studtable order by score desc
```

But since there is a tie of score for Alex and mathew, we need to get both of them on the final result. So how can I handle this situation when a tie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using subquery

```
select * from studtable 
where score in (select distinct top(3) score from studtable order by score desc)
order by score desc
```

Comment: Boss this will work only when a distinct in subquery..
I made it worked.. thanks
select * from studtable 
where score in (select distinct top(3) score from studtable order by score desc)
order by score desc

Comment: @sforsandeep : could you check my post ??

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select top 3 with ties * from studtable order by score desc
```

This'll get you top 3 including ties.

## [See it in Action](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/13597)

Comment: Actually our requirement is to select students with top 3 distinct scores. But when using this method, if 3 students having same score say 9 out of 10, other students get ignored. And obviously we cant determine who got second and third. But in the subquery method It will list all students who falls in first, second and third position. Thats exactly what the scenario is. Sorry if my question misleads..

Answer (score 1):

You can use comparisons in the `where` clause.  Something like this should work:

```
select top 3 *
from studtable
where score in (select top 3 score from studtable order by score desc)
order by score desc;
```

This returns all rows with the same score as any in the top 3, which is, I think, what you want.  If you want the top 3 distinct scores:

```
where score in (select top 3 score from studtable group by score order by score desc)
```

An alternative approach is to use ranking functions:

```
select st.*
from (select st.*, dense_rank() over (order by score desc) as seqnum
      from studtable
     ) st
where seqnum <= 3;
```

Comment: this query will return only 3 records again

Comment: @Cris . . . Actually, I don't think so.  It will return the top 3 scores in the inner query . . . 9, 8.2, and 7.  Then it will return the four rows that have one of those three scores.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : why use subquery or rank() sql-server can handle ties with `with ties` ?? jus a suggestion sir !

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi . . . Most databases don't support the `with ties` syntax.  More importantly, the OP was ambiguous about what the query really should be -- all the rows for three distinct scores or just the top three scorers with any remaining ties.  Consider if four people are all tied for the top score.

Answer (score 0):

```
select STA.* 
from studtable STA
inner join (SELECT Top 3 Score from studtable ORDER BY Score DESC) STB
on STA.Score = STB.Score
 order by STA.score desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from my_table where score in (select distinct score from my_table order by score desc limit 3) order by score desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using group by before order by  //this will improve performance as well

```
select top 3 * from studtable group by score order by score desc
```